# False Positive and False Negative

Tags: java

In static analysis, is there any examples explaining `false negative` and `false positive`?

For the ***null dereference analysis***?

Answer (score 2):

A false positive in general is when something is detected (i.e. "positive") when it's not there (i.e. "false").

A false negative in general is when something is *not* detected (i.e. "negative") when it is really there.

For null dereference analysis that means:

- a false positive is when it tells you that there is a potential null pointer dereference when in fact that can never happen at runtime.
- a false negative is when it fails to tell you about a potential null pointer dereference that can actually happen at runtime.

For example, consider this method:

```
public void frobnicate(Object foo) {
  int hash = foo.hashCode(); // line #1
  int hash2 = foo.hashCode(); // line #2
}
```

If the analysis tells you that there's a potential null pointer dereference at the line labelled "#2", then it is wrong because when execution reaches that point, `foo` can not be null. Therefore such a notification would be considered a false positive.

If the analysis *fails* to tells you that there's a potentital null pointer dereference at the line labelled "#1" then it would *also* be wrong, because `foo` can clearly be `null` at that point. That would be a false negative.